# Does MS SQL server actually support spatial joins?

Tags: sql, spatial-join, sql-server

I have tried these ways to run a spatial join

```
select * from a 
    join b on GEOMETRY::STWITHIN(a.geom, b.geom) = 1 

select * from a 
    join b on a.geom.STWITHIN(b.geom) = 1
```

Both return the error:

```
Could not find method 'stwithin' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'
```

I have tested on both MS SQL Server 2016 and 2019.

Comment: I think the method names for CLR-based methods are case-sensitive, try the second form with `STWithin`:
on a.geom.STWithin(b.geom) = 1

Comment: Oh wow!. You are right! Which is really strange as everything else is not case sensitive in SQL Server

Comment: Did using STWithin resolve your problem? If it did, you can write it as an answer.

Comment: Ok and I did that now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me per Michael's suggestion:

```
select * from a 
    join b on a.geom.STWithin(b.geom) = 1
```

Note that the `STWithin` function (which is apparently a CLR function) is case sensitive.